# set Icon gives error on JLabel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlabel, windowbuilder

I'm having an issue with trying to change the icon of a `JLabel`. I am using the windowbuilder addon in eclipse to make this program, so just disregard all the bad naming choices of the label and all that, they will be changed later.

The error I'm having is that at the bottom of the my code where I try to change the icon of `label_1`, I get the following message.

> The method seticon(icon) in the type jlabel is not applicable for the
>   arguments (string)

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Here is my code. Sorry that it's rather long, that's window builder for you I suppose:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class Game  {
public Timer bomb1;
public JLabel label;
public JLabel label_1;
public JLabel lblScore;
public JButton btnQuit;
public JLabel label_2;
public JLabel label_3;
public JLabel label_4;
public JLabel label_5;
public JLabel label_6;
public JLabel label_7;
public JLabel label_8;
public JLabel label_9;
public JLabel label_10;
public JLabel label_11;
public JLabel label_12;
public JLabel label_13;
public JLabel label_14;
public JLabel label_15;
public JLabel label_16;
public JLabel lblDodgeTheBombs;
public JFrame frame;
private JPanel contentPane;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Game window = new Game();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public Game() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 489, 512);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    label_1 = new JLabel("");
    label_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_1.setBounds(59, 44, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_1);

    label = new JLabel("0");
    label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    label.setBounds(71, 12, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(label);

    lblScore = new JLabel("Score:");
    lblScore.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblScore.setBounds(28, 11, 45, 17);
    contentPane.add(lblScore);

    btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");
    btnQuit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
    btnQuit.setBounds(359, 10, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnQuit);

    label_2 = new JLabel("");
    label_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_2.setBounds(149, 44, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_2);

    label_3 = new JLabel("");
    label_3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_3.setBounds(239, 44, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_3);

    label_4 = new JLabel("");
    label_4.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_4.setBounds(329, 44, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_4);

    label_5 = new JLabel("");
    label_5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_5.setBounds(59, 138, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_5);

    label_6 = new JLabel("");
    label_6.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_6.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_6.setBounds(149, 135, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_6);

    label_7 = new JLabel("");
    label_7.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_7.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_7.setBounds(239, 135, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_7);

    label_8 = new JLabel("");
    label_8.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_8.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_8.setBounds(329, 135, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_8);

    label_9 = new JLabel("");
    label_9.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_9.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_9.setBounds(329, 320, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_9);

    label_10 = new JLabel("");
    label_10.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_10.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_10.setBounds(59, 229, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_10);

    label_11 = new JLabel("");
    label_11.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_11.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_11.setBounds(149, 229, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_11);

    label_12 = new JLabel("");
    label_12.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_12.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_12.setBounds(239, 229, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_12);

    label_13 = new JLabel("");
    label_13.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_13.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_13.setBounds(329, 229, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_13);

    label_14 = new JLabel("");
    label_14.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_14.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_14.setBounds(239, 320, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_14);

    label_15 = new JLabel();
    label_15.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_15.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_15.setBounds(149, 320, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_15);

    label_16 = new JLabel("");
    label_16.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\WHITE.png"));
    label_16.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label_16.setBounds(59, 323, 80, 80);
    contentPane.add(label_16);

    lblDodgeTheBombs = new JLabel("Dodge the bombs!");
    lblDodgeTheBombs.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblDodgeTheBombs.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    lblDodgeTheBombs.setBounds(137, 418, 217, 33);
    contentPane.add(lblDodgeTheBombs);

    bomb1 = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());
    bomb1.start();
}
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label_1.setIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\blank.png");

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you solved with your problem?

Answer (score 4):

> The method seticon(icon) in the type jlabel is not applicable for the
>   arguments (string)

yes its because as per the doc found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) the setIcon() accepts a Icon as a parrameter not String. So, your code should be...

```
label_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\\blank.png"));
```

I recommend you to go with documentations in the future. Its really a very good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is self-explanatory about what went wrong. The "setIcon()" method expects instance of Icon class and not string instance.

```
jLabelObject.setIcon("string")    // Do not pass image path
```